# strtoll/_strtoi64 Parameter Issue

Tags: c, string, string-parsing

I am having trouble understanding this code:

```
static long long _be_decode_int(const char **data, long long *data_len)
{
    char *endp;
    long long ret = strtoll(*data, &endp, 10);
    *data_len -= (endp - *data);
    *data = endp;
    return ret;
}
```

I have changed `strtoll` to `_strtoi64` because I am programming on Windows and believe them to perform the same function.

According to the [MSDN page for _strtoi64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h80404d3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the second parameter should be a pointer to the character that ends the string. If `endp` has only just been declared, what does it point to?

Comment: strtoll returns there a pointer to the last character it has read during conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a "result parameter" -- you don't have to put anything into the pointer, and after the function returns it will point to the character after the number.

EDIT: this is also why you are passing &endp and not just endp -- the function needs a "pointer to the pointer" so it can fill in the pointer value